# How to use FirebaseUI in the current fragment?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I would like to create a TabLayout with two tabs - `Group1` and `Group2`.  Each group is a different set of people. For `Group1` we allow to connect only with email and password and for `Group2` we allow to connect only with phone number. I'm trying to add the FirebaseUI for each one of the tab's fragments.

With the help of the docs, I wrote the following `onCreateView` of fragment of `Group2`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group2_login, container, false);

    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                AuthUI.IdpConfig idpConfig = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().setDefaultCountryIso("IN").build();
                List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Collections.singletonList(idpConfig);
                Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setTheme(R.style.myauth).setAvailableProviders(providers).build();
                startActivityForResult(intent,RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    });

    return fragmentView;
}
```

But as I understand it will open the FirebaseUI in a new screen, instead of keeping it in the current one `group2_login`. How can I use the FirebaseUI in the fragment's UI?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase UI launches an [activity for result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) as you noticed.

I don't think what you want can be supported with FirebaseUI as it is, but there is the [repo of FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) where you can customize things as you want, and then build it as a custom dependency in your project.